# Scala Recursive Function with Future Return Type

Tags: scala, concurrency

I am writing a recursive retry function in scala where I want to know if there was a runtime error with the future creation.  If there is then future instantiation is retried.

Imagine I have a database query function:

```
dbLookup(userId : UserId) : Option[UserName] = ???
```

The retry would look something of the form:

```
retry[T](f : () => Future[Option[T]],  
         notifyFailure : (t : Throwable) => Unit,
         n : Int) : Future[Option[T]] = {
  if(n <= 0) { Future{None} }
  else {
    val fut = f()
    if(f.resultsInException) {      //I don't know how to write this
      notifyFailure(f.exception)
      retry(f, notifyFailure, n-1) //try again
    }
    else {
      f.originalValueAsFuture
    }
  }
}
```

**How can this future functionality be implemented and allow for tail recursion optimization?**

This function could be used to retry the database 10 times for a user if the execution context keeps throwing an exception when I try to create a Future:

```
val userNameAfterRetries = 
  retry(() => Future{dbLookup("1234")},
        (t) => system error (s"future creation error : $t"),
        10)
```

Note: this is sort of possible with `Future.fallbackTo`, but unfortunately fallbackTo takes in a `Future[T]` rather than a `() => Future[T]`.  This is important because using fallbackTo would result in retrying at least 1 extra times even if the first attempt was successful.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Can you use "onFailure" from Future? Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: @Jegan `onFailure` can "register" the notifyFailure to run if a failure ocurrs, but then I need to return the value of a retry...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
  def retry[T](f: () => Future[Option[T]],
               notifyFailure: Throwable => Unit,
               n: Int)(implicit ec : ExecutionContext): Future[Option[T]] = {
    if (n <= 0) Future.failed(new RuntimeException("Exceeded number of allowed retries"))
    else f().recoverWith { case originalError => notifyFailure(originalError); retry(f, notifyFailure, n - 1) }
  }
```

**Update on tail recursion**: The nature of `Future` is asynchronous so unless you want to `await` for result, I do not quite see it being possible to make it `@tailrec` because you will have to use recursion in callback.

*Also practical note:* if you know it is always ~10 retries, I would not be afraid of recursion.

Comment: UPDATE: Actually simplified solution to the tiniest one possible :)

Comment: I think, the question asks for tail recursive solution.

Comment: It actually is, have a look at "else" part, it recovers future with recursive call to "retry" method

Comment: It is actually not, try adding the @tailrec annotation to your method. But, I would be fine with this :-) as 'n' here can be only 10.

Comment: Yes, you are right. retry call is not in tail position. I can try to think of tail recursive solution but probably later today :)

Comment: @tkachuko I added an implicit ec to make the function compile, but thanks for the answer and clarification on tail recursion.